# Is there anything wrong with using foreign language typeface in English?

Tags: fonts, print-design, typefaces

I'm working on a CV design and came across Gulim, which is a Korean typeface. I like the way it renders Roman characters as well. Is there anything wrong with using typefaces designed for foreign alphabets with the Roman alphabet?

Comment: As long as you make sure to embed the font I guess it doesn't really matter what kind of font you use if it contains all the characters you need. I looked the font up and used the preview but I noticed (at least in the preview) that it gets quite awkward when smaller than 24pt, so maybe that's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all, unless you run with problems with any sort of diacritics or special characters of the language you are typing, since english, doesn't have any of this, you should be fine.

If the typeface works well, it doesn't really matter if it was designed for an specific language, actually it is really cool to know they've designed a roman typeface altogether in the korean set so text can be mixed up harmonically.

Just be sure to embed it at the PDF or at least convert it to outlines if it doesn't embed properly.